# Why does using rand/rand_core with #![no_std] result in "duplicate lang item"?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to generate random numbers using `rand` or `rand_core`. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/rust-random/rand), `#![no_std]` usage can be enabled using `default-features = false`. So I tried doing that for both `rand` and `rand_core` to see if either works. I get the same errors in both cases, so I'm showing what I did for `rand_core`.

```
rand_core = {version = "0.5.1", default-features = false}
```

And then importing it as:

```
use rand_core::RngCore;
```

However, I get the following errors (I haven't written this part of the code):

```
error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `oom`
   --> src/alloc.rs:116:1
    |
116 | / fn alloc_error_handler(layout: Layout) -> ! {
117 | |     panic!("allocation error: {:?}", layout)
118 | | }
    | |_^
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `rand_core` depends on)

error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
  --> src/panic.rs:21:1
   |
21 | / fn panic(info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
22 | |     let mut host_stderr = ErStderr::default();
23 | |
24 | |     writeln!(host_stderr, "{}", info).ok();
25 | |
26 | |     unsafe {libc::exit(1); }
27 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `rand_core` depends on)

error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `eh_personality`
  --> src/panic.rs:29:28
   |
29 | #[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `panic_unwind` (which `std` depends on)
```

Here is a minimal working example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e748b901ea22742c878e8208d9c0691

I am using nightly.

This is my `Cargo.toml`.

```
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
cbindgen = "0.12.2"
rand_core = {version = "0.5.1", default-features=false}

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Worth nothing there's no `OsRng` in rand_core, so I think your code should have failed before getting to the error you say it did. Ensure that you are compiling the right thing and saving modified files.

Comment: @Shepmaster https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_core/struct.OsRng.html <- This is where I found OsRng.
Working on the MRE.

Comment: @Shepmaster In particular, I'm trying to replicate this example: https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_core/struct.OsRng.html#usage-example

Comment: I would not trust that documentation as it has no version number associated with it. [The documentation for 0.5.1](https://docs.rs/rand_core/0.5.1/rand_core/) is different.

Comment: @Shepmaster Updated to remove `OsRng`.

Comment: My main point was that I believe that when you had `OsRng` in there, you should have gotten a compiler error *far* before you got to "duplicate lang items". That makes me suspicious that you aren't editing/saving/compiling the thing(s) that you think you are.

Comment: @Shepmaster Looks like it didn't give me an error because `OsRng` is present in the source: https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/master/rand_core/src/os.rs#L47

Comment: Yes, but only [if that feature is enabled](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/rand_core-0.5.1/rand_core/src/lib.rs#L51), which you've disabled. That means something else is enabling that feature and you need to remove it / fix it. Again, you'll find it as part of your MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works, but when I remove `cbindgen` from the list of dependencies, everything automatically works.

Comment: Because `cbindgen` depends on `rand` and isn't disabling the default features. That's [what I meant earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749592/why-does-using-rand-rand-core-with-no-std-result-in-duplicate-lang-item#comment107483502_60749592).